# Implement http methods using Net TCP with exiting WCF services in net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, wcf

as you see below is my  main method were was setting up the endpoint URL, soap action and request(XML)

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
                {
                    string request = string.Empty;
                    string soapAction = string.Empty;
                    string endPoint = string.Empty;
        
                    
                    GetSoapRequest("PROFILEENROMMENT", ref request, ref soapAction, ref endPoint);
                
                    var result = ExecuteSoap(request.ToString(), soapAction, endPoint);
                    Console.WriteLine(result.Result);
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }
```

this function will call first and set API ,request(XML) and soap action link

```
private static void GetSoapRequest(string api, ref string request, ref string soapAction, ref string endPoint)
        {
            if (api == "PROFILEENROMMENT")
            {
                endPoint = "https://something.somedomain.com/PiiProvider.svc";
                soapAction = "http://www.somedomain.com/schema/pii/v1/IPiiProviderTransaction/ProfileEnrollment";
                request = XDocument.Load(@"ProfileEnrollment.xml").Root.ToString();
            }

        }
```

below is the final function which will call the SOAP web services with HTTPClient class call with sending required POST URL, SOAP action, HTTP content, method type Post and content type XML and will get a response.

```
private static async Task<string> ExecuteSoap(string soapRequest, string soapAction, string url)
    {
        //handlers
        var socketsHandler = new SocketsHttpHandler
        {
            PooledConnectionLifetime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10),
            PooledConnectionIdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
            MaxConnectionsPerServer = 10
        };

        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(socketsHandler);
        HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(soapRequest);
        HttpResponseMessage response;
       
        // If your Service have any Authorization tokens, you have to pass those in the below format.
        //httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

        HttpRequestMessage req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url);
        req.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", soapAction);
        req.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate");
        req.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
        req.Content = httpContent;
        req.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("text/xml; charset=utf-8");


        // Here you will get the Reponse from service
        response = await httpClient.SendAsync(req);
        // Converting the response into text format
        var responseBodyAsText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return responseBodyAsText;
    }
```

how to implement HTTP methods like Get,post,put using NetTCP?

Comment: WCF is not supported in dotnet core nor within aspnetcore.

Comment: @Aron Thanks for the reply, is there any chance to call net.tcp service from Dot net core soap?

Comment: None at all. The HttpBasic binding for WCF implements the SOAP protocol, that is why DotNetCore Soap works. Net.Tcp is a completely different protocol. It would be like asking, can I connect to an SSH server using `HttpWebClient`.

Comment: @Aron Hi Aron can we implement SocketsHttpHandler  in TcpClient?

Comment: none of what you are asking makes any sense at all. Net TCP and Http are mutually exclusive. They are on the same OSI level. It's like asking how you can use your mouth to speak American Sign Language.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect to a WCF service that exposes Net.Tcp bindings from a dotnet core application, you can try using CoreWCF.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/CoreWCF.NetTcp/

However, I've yet to try this relatively immature project.